# How to customize bootstrap carousel-indicators

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

I have this Bootstrap carousel image but currently the indicators display from 0-3. But i want to change it from 1-4 and also numbering is not centered in the box.

this is from html part.

```
<div id="screenShot" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
   <div class="item" ng-class="{'active':$first}" ng-repeat="s in app.appScreenShot">
    <img src={{s}} />
   </div>
   </div>
   <div>
    <!-- Indicators -->
     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#screenShot" data-slide-to="{{$index}}" ng-class="{'active':$first}" ng-repeat="s in app.appScreenShot">{{$index}}</li>
     </ol>
   </div>
</div>
```

And this is from the CSS part.

```
<style>
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    margin: auto;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-indent: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #ffff99;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: try **{{$index+1}}** or **{{$index}}+1** for increasing number value.

Comment: @Atula it works for `{{$index+1}}` but not for centering the number in the indicators

Comment: text-align:center and padding:auto;

Comment: @Atula tried but also not changing anything

Comment: try to give padding to the indicator container...like padding-top,bottom...etc

Comment: @Atula tried but indicators itself changing not numbers inside the indicators. btw thanks

Comment: I think you have to do it on your own :-)